# null value in column idevent violates constraint not null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Projet service

```
public Projet createProjet(Projet p, Long idcontact) {

    // Contact c = contactrepository.findByAdresseemail(idcontact);
    Contact c = contactrepository.findOne(idcontact);
    Statut s = statutrepository.findByEtat("encours");

    // statutrepository.save(s);
    Projet projet = projetrepository.save(p);
    projet.setContact(c);
    projet.setStatut(s);
    projet.setDateannonce(DateTime.now().toString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"));
    Event e = new Event();
    e.setAction("Ajout");
    e.setDescription("ajout projet");
    e.setDate(DateTime.now().toString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"));
    e.setProjet(projet);
    this.eventrepo.save(e);

    return this.projetrepository.save(p);

}
```

I want to save new event when save a new project, but when I want to save the project with the event I have this error:

> null value in column idevent

Comment: you don't set you idevent property and probably you have no auto id generation in your entity class

Comment: so, either add an id, or configure your db for auto-increment

Comment: I set the id  with generation identity in my class event . im usisng postgres db

Comment: Can you share Project and Event entities.